# Angular 8 alert or confirm function does nothing in (click) code section

Tags: angular

In Angular V8, the system function such as `alert('')` or `confirm('')` as well as `if(..)` statement if executed within the template/html section using `(click)="..."`, they do not work.

For e.g.

### 1. Alert Function

```
<!--  -->
<input type='button' value=`Alert` (click)="alert('Alert')"
```

#### Error

```
SomeComponent.html:49 ERROR TypeError: _co.alert is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:42925
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
```

### 2. Confirm Function

```
<!--  -->
<input type='button' value=`Confirm` (click)="confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')"
```

#### Error

```
SomeComponent.html:49 ERROR TypeError: _co.confirm is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:42925
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
```

### 3. if statement

```
<!--  -->
<input type='button' value=`Check` (click)="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')){}"
```

#### Error

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token if at column 1 in [if (confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')){}]
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should not work !

The event binding listens for the element's click ( `input` in your case) events and calls the component's (**TS part of that html**) method whenever a click occurs.

If you want it to work:

```
<input type="button" value="Check" (click)="clickMethod()">
```

TS part:

```
clickMethod() {
  alert('clicked');
}
```

[Check this link](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding).

Comment: I am going through the given link.

Comment: I understand now. The functions from system/window are considered as part of TS therefore `_co.alert` is displayed in the logs. Regarding `if` statement, Angular is developed to throw parse error whenever it encounters conditional keywords (or maybe even other keywords) such as `if`. The same thing happens with `while` and `for`.